# "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, valueerror

Many people ask questions like this, **BUT** many of them are using not standart library, so their error can be explained (for me). I used standart Tkinter library but i get this error too.

```
  File "C:/Users/Panda/Desktop/Пайтон/enter_symbol.py", line 5, in <module>
    exec(f'tk.bind({chr(num)},lambda event:print("You entered:",{chr(num)}))')
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
tk=Tk()
tk.geometry('0x0+0+0')
for num in range(1000):
    exec(f"""
try:tk.bind({chr(num)},lambda event:print("You entered:",{chr(num)}))
except:None""")
```

What should I do to not get this error?

Comment: `chr(0)` is your issue. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't need to call `chr()`, just use `{num}`.

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? That's something you really shouldn't be using in the way you're using it.

Comment: @Reti43 i am trying to bind every symbol from 1st to 1000th

Comment: @BryanOakley cuz i want to save `chr(num)` in this function

Comment: You don't seem to understand what `tk.bind` does. It binds specific events (specifically designed strings) to a function callback. `tk.bind('<Key>', lambda event: print(event))` will almost do what you want to detect any keyboard press.

Comment: You don't need to use `exec` to use `chr(num)`.